# UI Dialog Tooltip

Tags: jquery, user-interface, dialog, tooltip

I'm searching for a tooltips that should function within a UI dialog, but after searching and  testing several tooltips (like cluetip) i have no succes.. :-s

I've tested jquery Cluetip. This tooltip showed up when i mouve the mouseover a link/img, but the tooltip has showed BEHIND the ui dialog... ??? A z-index problem i guess. I've searched, but i could not find the clue.

Can someone tell me what tooltip i need to show some info when i move my mouse over a link or image within an ui dialog?

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't the tooltip have a css class you can define for it, so you can set your own z-index value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you invoke the Cluetip code, are you specifying a z-index in Cluetip's options? For example, `$('a.link').cluetip({cluezIndex: '1010'});`. The jQuery UI dialog uses a z-index of 1001 by default. So stick the Cluetip a little bit higher. Hope that works for you.

Comment: Ok, cool! This works! I didn't take a closer look to the ClueTip options, but this is the solution.